# Allow a user or role to view drafts and previews, but not other admin privileges?

Tags: php, functions, users, user-roles, capabilities

How do I allow a specific user or a specific role to view drafts and previews, but not allow them to edit posts or have any other admin capabilities? I can add a custom capability to a role, but don't know the logic for allowing them to view drafts and previews. Any thoughts?

Comment: there's no read only view for the editor in the backend, the only way you could do this is by forcing users to the drafts preview

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an easier way. I gave them the `edit_other_posts` and `edit_other_pages` role capabilities, and then blocked their access to the admin area using the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'eri_block_nonadmins_init' );
function eri_block_nonadmins_init() {
    $current_url = eri_get_current_url( true, false);
    if ( (!current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && !( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )) 
        && (is_admin() || $current_url == '/cornerstone/') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Of course, I also blocked them from gaining access to our Cornerstone front-end editor.

If you're interested in what the `eri_get_current_url()` function does:

```
function eri_get_current_url( $params = true, $domain = true ){
    if ($domain) {
        $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http';
        $domain = $protocol."://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
    } else {
        $domain = '';
    }

    $full_url = $domain.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (!$params) {
        return strtok($full_url, '?');
    } else {
        return $full_url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow a normally excluded role to access previews is to harness the `posts_results` hook, in conjunction with an `is_preview` condition. Here's an example for the `contributor` role.

```
   function contributor_preview_access( $posts ) {
    
        if (
            is_preview()
            && ! empty( $posts )
            && in_array( 'contributor', wp_get_current_user()->roles, true )
        ) {
            $posts[0]->post_status = 'publish';
        }
    
        return $posts;
    }
    
    add_filter( 'posts_results', 'contributor_preview_access', 10, 2 );
```